# GetFollowerIDs function is not working anymore

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='aaa',consumer_secret='aaa', access_token_key='aaa', access_token_secret='aaa')

followers=api.GetFollowerIDs()
```

That code was working 4 days ago. But suddenly stop to work. It gives error below. I am using python-twitter. What's the reason of that?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-1.0.1-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 3320, in GetFollowerIDs
    total_count -= len(data['ids'])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

EDIT: All code is above. It was correctly working code 3-4 days ago.

EDIT2: If you want you can look error line from here. I am using that library. https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter.py

Comment: Generally, errors like this are likely candidates for desync between implementation and API. Have you checked Twitters changelog to see if there have been any changes made recently?

Comment: it seems your total_count is a none can you post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here:

```
a = None
a -= 5 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

for some reason your `total_count` variable is set to None